# Redirect path to home, with path string as a GET variable using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, http-status-code-301

I am trying dynamically to redirect all links of the form

```
example.com/path1
example.com/path2
example.com/path3
...
```

to

```
example.com?src=path1
example.com?src=path2
example.com?src=path3
...
```

A static rule would be the following

```
Redirect /path1 https://example.com?src=path1
```

But I want to do this with **every** possible string. Any ideas how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following, written based on shown samples. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ ?src=$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Works flawlessly (as long as you edit your last line to `RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ https://example.com?src=$1 [R=301,L]`. Thank you so much!!!